# c6.s081 lab1 xargs：I don't know why the program below can't get the answer?

Tags: c, malloc, fork, xargs, xv6

when I was finishing the c6.s081(2021) lab1 xargs, I found a function from other person which is below:

```
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/param.h"
#include "user/user.h"

#define STDIN_FILENO 0
#define MAXLINE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char* params[MAXARG];
    int n, args_index = 0;
    int i;

    char* cmd = argv[1];
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) params[args_index++] = argv[i];

    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        if (fork() == 0) // child process
        {
            char *arg = (char*) malloc(sizeof(line));
            int index = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\n')
                {
                    arg[index] = 0;
                    params[args_index++] = arg;
                    index = 0;
                    arg = (char*) malloc(sizeof(line));
                }
                else arg[index++] = line[i];
            }
            arg[index] = 0;
            params[args_index] = 0;
            exec(cmd, params);
        }
        else wait((int*)0);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

when I try to run it by the code

```
mkdir a
echo hello > a/b
mkdir c
echo hello > c/b
echo hello > b
find . b | xargs grep hello
```

It's output will be below:

```
*** Now run 'gdb' in another window.

xv6 kernel is booting

hart 1 starting
hart 2 starting
init: starting sh
$ sh < xargstest.sh
$ echo DONE
$ $ $ $ $ $ $ DONEqemu-system-riscv64: terminating on signal 15 from pid 7325 (make)
```

I don't know why there is no output except $(which means The output has many $ because the xv6 shell doesn't realize it is processing commands from a file instead of from the console, and prints a $ for each command in the file.)

I have try to debug it:

1. I try to output the variable n, It output 1 in the first loop and nothing else. so I find in the second loop, the read will return 0,and so the loop will end.
2. I tried to output the content of line, and found there is nothing except the char '.'
3. I also delete some sentence wonder to test, and found that if I delete the sentence included in if(fork()){},it will get the data from pipe.
4. I think the wrong should be caused by the malloc or the fork??

Comment: Not necessarily your problem, but unless you are writing a device driver or kernel loadable module or something similar, you normally shouldn't use headers under the `<kernel/…>` sub-tree.  You should be using `<stdlib.h>`, `<unistd.h>` , `<sys/wait.h>`.

Comment: Most people on SO will have no clue what "c6.s081(2021)" is, beyond it's a course designator at some institute of higher education somewhere.  Either explain what it is and where we can find the information about it, or don't mention it.  Explain that program is meant to be a simple version of `xargs` — it is implied, but not stated (but it's better to state it).  And there are better exemplars than the code you've chosen to use.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I'm sorry for my omission.,And as you comment the c6.s081  is a MIT open course for operation system. The program above is a simplified implementation of xargs. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.